# setInterval and clearInterval in javaScript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

```js
let count = 0;

function printCount() {
  console.log("Count:", count);
  count++;

  if (count > 5) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}

let intervalId = setInterval(printCount, 1000); clearInterval(intervalId);
```

I do not understand why its not working on Google Chrome console. Can you help me please?

Comment: It's working for me. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: `your text` - what's this?

Answer (score 0):

The `clearInterval(intervalId)`; line is placed right after the `setInterval` function, so it clears the interval immediately after setting it.

Try removing the `clearInterval(intervalId);` line outside of the `setInterval` call, and it should work as expected:

```js
let count = 0;

function printCount() {
  console.log("Count:", count);
  count++;

  if (count > 5) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}

let intervalId = setInterval(printCount, 1000);
// clearInterval(intervalId); // Remove this line
```

Now, the interval should continue running until the count is greater than 5.

Answer (score -1):

clearInterval is executed right after setInterval.
Below may be work

```
let count = 0;

function printCount() {
  console.log("Count:", count);
  count++;

  if (count > 5) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}

let intervalId = setInterval(printCount, 1000);
```